# Convert SQL Server datetime in UTC to specific timezone

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to convert a datetime stored as UTC to a specific timezone, stored in another column.

For example, given this table:

```
Date             | TimeZone
-----------------+---------------
2017-05-15 11:17 | Europe/Madrid
2017-01-01 11:17 | Europe/Madrid
2017-05-15 11:17 | US/Pacific
2017-01-01 11:17 | US/Pacific
```

I should get this result:

```
Date
----------------
2017-05-15 13:17
2017-01-01 12:17
2017-05-15 04:17
2017-01-01 03:17
```

Please note I'm using SQL Server 2012, so I can't use `AT TIME ZONE`. Is there any way to achieve this without post-processing the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one use TimeZoneInfo in a SQLCLR assembly in SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581510/how-does-one-use-timezoneinfo-in-a-sqlclr-assembly-in-sql-server-2012). The answer contains a link to a project that will add TZ support to SQL Server 2008 R2+.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use SQL 2012 Server to convert UTC time to base local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12452430/use-sql-2012-server-to-convert-utc-time-to-base-local-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not that easy. You'd need information about different time zones and rules of daylight-saving switches etc.
I'm using [sqltz](https://github.com/mj1856/SqlServerTimeZoneSupport) library for all my timezone-related needs.

```
  SELECT LocalDate = Tzdb.UtcToLocal(UTCDate, TimeZone, 1, 1)
  FROM Table
```

sqltz uses IANA time zone database, Microsoft uses different standard so names of time zones are different. Europe/Madrid and US/Pacific are in IANA database